# How to remove all values from an array before a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have the following array and I need to remove all values before key 83 with value BEGIN:VEVENT. I need to do this not by key but with the value only.

```
   Array ( [75] => END:DAYLIGHT [76] => BEGIN:STANDARD [77] => DTSTART:20211031T030000 [78] => TZOFFSETFROM:+0300 [79] => TZOFFSETTO:+0200 [80] => TZNAME:EET [81] => END:STANDARD [82] => END:VTIMEZONE [83] => BEGIN:VEVENT [84] => SUMMARY: [85] => DESCRIPTION: Tourist Agent Office: First Name: Last Name: Email: xxx@gma [86] => il.com Visitors: 1 Phone: Details: Time Slots: 12:00 μμ - 11:59 πμ [87] => [88] => DTSTART:20200711T120001 [89] => DTEND:20200725T115902 [90] => UID:2020-07-11 12:00:01_25@demo.icalendar.org [91] => DTSTAMP:20200604T130218 [92] => CREATED:20200129T104306 [93] => LAST-MODIFIED:20200129T104306 [94] => STATUS:CONFIRMED [95] => END:VEVENT [96] => BEGIN:VEVENT [97] => SUMMARY: [98] => DESCRIPTION: Tourist Agent Office: First Name: Last Name: Email: xxx@gma [99] => il.com Visitors: 1 Phone: Details: Time Slots: 12:00 μμ - 11:59 πμ [100] => [101] => DTSTART:20200912T120001 [102] => DTEND:20200926T115902 [103] => UID:2020-09-12 12:00:01_26@demo.icalendar.org [104] => DTSTAMP:20200604T130218 [105] => CREATED:20200203T060059 [106] => LAST-MODIFIED:20200203T060059 [107] => STATUS:CONFIRMED [108] => END:VEVENT [109] => END:VCALENDAR [110] =>)
```

I 've tried so far ...

```
$result = array_slice($array, array_search('BEGIN:VEVENT', $array) ?: 0);

print_r($array);
```

where $array is the above example

this returns same array

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are the issues you 're experiencing with this task? Remember: SO is not a coding service where you meet people who are doing your job. Show us some code and we 'll try to help you.

Comment: I tried the following code but no success: /
/ Find the position of the key you're looking for.
$position = array_search(BEGIN:VEVENT, array_values($array));

// If a position is found, splice the array.
if ($position !== false) {
    array_splice($array, ($position - 1));
}

var_dump($array);
where $array is the example above array
As you understand I want to clear all DTSTART before BEGIN:VEVENT as DTSTART before that value is not info I need to store in mysql.

Comment: Since this is not your first question here on SO try to add what you 've tried so far for yourself the next time. I 've edited your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short one liner ...

```
$data = [
    75 => 'END:DAYLIGHT',
    76 => 'BEGIN:STANDARD', 
    77 => 'DTSTART:20211031T030000',
    78 => 'TZOFFSETFROM:+0300', 
    79 => 'TZOFFSETTO:+0200', 
    80 => 'TZNAME:EET', 
    81 => 'END:STANDARD',
    82 => 'END:VTIMEZONE',
    83 => 'BEGIN:VEVENT',
    84 => 'SUMMARY:',
    85 => 'DESCRIPTION: Tourist Agent Office: First Name: Last Name: Email: xxx@gma',
    86 => 'il.com Visitors: 1 Phone: Details: Time Slots: 12:00 μμ - 11:59 πμ', 
    87 => '',
    88 => 'DTSTART:20200711T120001',
    89 => 'DTEND:20200725T115902', 
    90 => 'UID:2020-07-11 12:00:01_25@demo.icalendar.org', 
    91 => 'DTSTAMP:20200604T130218',
    92 => 'CREATED:20200129T104306', 
    93 => 'LAST-MODIFIED:20200129T104306',
    94 => 'STATUS:CONFIRMED',
    95 => 'END:VEVENT', 
    96 => 'BEGIN:VEVENT', 
    97 => 'SUMMARY:',
    98 => 'DESCRIPTION: Tourist Agent Office: First Name: Last Name: Email: xxx@gma', 
    99 => 'il.com Visitors: 1 Phone: Details: Time Slots: 12:00 μμ - 11:59 πμ',
    100 => '',
    101 => 'DTSTART:20200912T120001',
    102 => 'DTEND:20200926T115902',
    103 => 'UID:2020-09-12 12:00:01_26@demo.icalendar.org',
    104 => 'DTSTAMP:20200604T130218', 
    105 => 'CREATED:20200203T060059',
    106 => 'LAST-MODIFIED:20200203T060059',
    107 => 'STATUS:CONFIRMED',
    108 => 'END:VEVENT',
    109 => 'END:VCALENDAR',
];

$result = array_slice($data, array_search('BEGIN:VEVENT', array_values($data)) ?: 0);
var_dump($result);
```

The function [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) searches the first occurance of `BEGIN:VEVENT` and returns the offset found recognizing the values of your original array with [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). This key you can use as offset for the [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function, which returns the rest of the array.

If `BEGIN:VEVENT` is not present in the given array the whole array will be returned.

The result from the above given example:

```
array(27) {
    [0] => string(12) "BEGIN:VEVENT"
    [1] => string(8) "SUMMARY:"
    [2] => string(72) "DESCRIPTION: Tourist Agent Office: First Name: Last Name: Email: xxx@gma"
    [3] => string(70) "il.com Visitors: 1 Phone: Details: Time Slots: 12:00 μμ - 11:59 πμ"
    [4] => string(0) ""
    [5] => string(23) "DTSTART:20200711T120001"
    [6] => string(21) "DTEND:20200725T115902"
    [7] => string(45) "UID:2020-07-11 12:00:01_25@demo.icalendar.org"
    [8] => string(23) "DTSTAMP:20200604T130218"
    [9] => string(23) "CREATED:20200129T104306"
    [10] => string(29) "LAST-MODIFIED:20200129T104306"
    [11] => string(16) "STATUS:CONFIRMED"
    [12] => string(10) "END:VEVENT"
    [13] => string(12) "BEGIN:VEVENT"
    [14] => string(8) "SUMMARY:"
    [15] => string(72) "DESCRIPTION: Tourist Agent Office: First Name: Last Name: Email: xxx@gma"
    [16] => string(70) "il.com Visitors: 1 Phone: Details: Time Slots: 12:00 μμ - 11:59 πμ"
    [17] => string(0) ""
    [18] => string(23) "DTSTART:20200912T120001"
    [19] => string(21) "DTEND:20200926T115902"
    [20] => string(45) "UID:2020-09-12 12:00:01_26@demo.icalendar.org"
    [21] => string(23) "DTSTAMP:20200604T130218"
    [22] => string(23) "CREATED:20200203T060059"
    [23] => string(29) "LAST-MODIFIED:20200203T060059"
    [24] => string(16) "STATUS:CONFIRMED"
    [25] => string(10) "END:VEVENT"
    [26] => string(13) "END:VCALENDAR"
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and this works fine but in my array it does not work. This is exactly I want to do I need to remove all key - values before the BEGIN:VEEVENT value.

Comment: There are all keys removed. The new array as a result of `array_slice` begins with the key 0. So you want to keep the keys from the position the needle is found onwards? Perhaps its better, when you edit your question and give an example, how the final array should look like?

Comment: i want to keep all values after the BEGIN:VEVENT appears and remove all values before that. so new array begins 0=> BEGIN:VEVENT  and goes on with the next values.

Comment: I understand as I tested your code in my server and works absolutely fine. But when I try to do this in my array it does not work. It returns same array as before slice.

Comment: Then you 're doing something wrong. Edit your question and show your code.

Comment: I can't share the array here as it is too long. How can I share it with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215305/discussion-between-a-v-and-marcel).

Comment: Nope. Try to reduce your array and edit your question so that every SO user can see, what exactly your problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: Edited the answer and added `array_values()` for finding the right offset for shortening your array. The result begins with 0 beginning from the first occurance of `BEGIN:VEVENT`.

Comment: I understand but if you can help me as this array is dynamic from a curl from ical link. The code i use  is $array = explode("\n",$server_output); where $server_output is the response from ical link. What do I need to change to have your format so I can use slice?

Comment: That was not your question. Open another question on SO and ask how to convert the ICAL/ICS server response into the array structure you expect. Describe the situation how it is, what you tried so far und how the expected result should look like.